# Accessing current value of property in setter

Tags: python, class, properties, setter

In Python, is it possible to **access the current value of a class variable inside its setter**?

For example:

```
# Getter
@property
# ...

# Setter
@position.setter
def position(self, value):
    # Do something with current value...
    # self.position, self.__position, position and __position don't seem to work

    # Update position with the given value
    self.__position = value

    # Do something with the new value...
```

The equivalent in C# would be:

```
private Position position;

public Position Position
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }

    set
    {
        // Do something with the current value...

        // Update position field with given object
        position = value;

        // Do something with the new value...
    }
}
```

**Update**
Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to better illustrate my question:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print(self.x)
        self.__x = value
        print(self.x)

c = C()
```

The following error is thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '_C__x'
```

This occurs because the setter tries to print the variable's current value before updating it, and the setter is run when `x` is set to 2 inside `__init__`, at which point `x` has not previously been assigned a value (there is no current value to print).

Comment: What do you mean *"don't seem to work"*? Until you've assigned to it, `self.__position` is still the old value, and `self.position` will therefore also access the old value.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but trying to access `self.position` or `self.__position` inside the setter both result in the following error: `AttributeError: 'GameObject' object has no attribute '_GameObject__position'`. (`GameObject` is the class containing the `position` variable.)

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Also consider ditching the `__double_underscore`, as name mangling unnecessarily complicates things.

Comment: While making an MCV example, I found the errors were thrown when setting the variable for the first time in `__init__`, at which point the variable has not yet been assigned a value. How would one check for this case?

Comment: @jonrsharpe With regards to the double underscores, I mistakenly thought they were required when updating a class variable's value within its setter.

Comment: You can use a `_single_underscore` to indicate private by convention *without* name mangling. Could you [edit] the MCVE *into the question?*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added MCVE to question.

Comment: Evidently you see the problem, so it's not clear what you're asking. If you access the previous value in the setter, how do you expect it to work the very first time? Handle the error and/or set the backing attribute directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll update the question. I was unsure how to handle such an error, but MSeifert's answer has cleared that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `self.x` (using the setter) in your `__init__`. But in your `x.setter` you `print(self.x)` (using the getter) before actually setting your value.

You could define a default-value (for example as class attribute) to make it work:

```
class C:
    __x = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print(self.x)
        self.__x = value
        print(self.x)

>>> c = C()
None
2
```

Note that double underscored variables are subject to ["name mangling"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) and the convention is that one uses single underscored variables instead.

Another way would be to `try` to access it and if it's not avaiable then return something else (or do something else):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        try:
            return self.__x
        except AttributeError:
            # I return "None" here but you could also do something else
            return None

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print(self.x)
        self.__x = value
        print(self.x)
```

which yields the same result:

```
>>> c = C()
None
2
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there a way of doing this without making the variable "static" (without initialising `__x` outside of `__init__`)?

Comment: @Ruben9922 I've added another way that catches the exception in the "getter". Does that answer your question? Note that you could also do the `try`, `except` around the first `print`-statement in your setter. Maybe to skip that if no attribute was set yet.